# snort 2.9.7.0 unable to load rule from local.conf while in test mode

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, snort, network-security

I am following the 'Snort 2.9.6.2 on Ubuntu 12 LTS and 14 LTS' guide to run snort in NIDS mode on my ubuntu 12.04.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/050/original/Snort_2.9.6.2_on_Ubuntu.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1415002618&Signature=IfheMZWyL%2BB1PULrNDHCb7dkGTk%3D

To test Snort, I created a simple rule that will cause Snort to generate an alert whenever Snort sees an ICMP \Echo request" or \Echo reply" messages.
Wrote the following line into the empty /etc/snort/rules/local.conf:

alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP test"; sid:10000001; rev:001;)

Now I tested the configuration file again but it has not loaded the rule from local.conf. Typed the following command:

sudo snort -T -c /etc/snort/snort.conf

I should have got the following output:

```
+-------------------[Rule Port Counts]---------------------------------------
|             tcp     udp    icmp      ip
|     src       0       0       0       0
|     dst       0       0       0       0
|     any       0       0       1       0
|      nc       0       0       1       0
|     s+d       0       0       0       0
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But instead I got the following output on terminal.Both fields are still 0.

---

```
Running in Test mode

        --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
Initializing Preprocessors!
Initializing Plug-ins!
Parsing Rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf"
PortVar 'HTTP_PORTS' defined :  [ 80:81 311 383 591 593 901 1220 1414 1741 1830 2301 2381 2809 3037 3128 3702 4343 4848 5250 6988 7000:7001 7144:7145 7510 7777 7779 8000 8008 8014 8028 8080 8085 8088 8090 8118 8123 8180:8181 8243 8280 8300 8800 8888 8899 9000 9060 9080 9090:9091 9443 9999 11371 34443:34444 41080 50002 55555 ]
PortVar 'SHELLCODE_PORTS' defined :  [ 0:79 81:65535 ]
PortVar 'ORACLE_PORTS' defined :  [ 1024:65535 ]
PortVar 'SSH_PORTS' defined :  [ 22 ]
PortVar 'FTP_PORTS' defined :  [ 21 2100 3535 ]
PortVar 'SIP_PORTS' defined :  [ 5060:5061 5600 ]
PortVar 'FILE_DATA_PORTS' defined :  [ 80:81 110 143 311 383 591 593 901 1220 1414 1741 1830 2301 2381 2809 3037 3128 3702 4343 4848 5250 6988 7000:7001 7144:7145 7510 7777 7779 8000 8008 8014 8028 8080 8085 8088 8090 8118 8123 8180:8181 8243 8280 8300 8800 8888 8899 9000 9060 9080 9090:9091 9443 9999 11371 34443:34444 41080 50002 55555 ]
PortVar 'GTP_PORTS' defined :  [ 2123 2152 3386 ]
Detection:
   Search-Method = AC-Full-Q
    Split Any/Any group = enabled
    Search-Method-Optimizations = enabled
    Maximum pattern length = 20
Tagged Packet Limit: 256
Loading dynamic engine /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so... done
Loading all dynamic detection libs from /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules...
WARNING: No dynamic libraries found in directory /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules.
  Finished Loading all dynamic detection libs from /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
Loading all dynamic preprocessor libs from /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/...
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_modbus_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dce2_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ssh_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dns_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_gtp_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ssl_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_smtp_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_dnp3_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_sdf_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_reputation_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_pop_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_imap_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_sip_preproc.so... done
  Loading dynamic preprocessor library /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor//libsf_ftptelnet_preproc.so... done
  Finished Loading all dynamic preprocessor libs from /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/
Log directory = /var/log/snort
WARNING: ip4 normalizations disabled because not inline.
WARNING: tcp normalizations disabled because not inline.
WARNING: icmp4 normalizations disabled because not inline.
WARNING: ip6 normalizations disabled because not inline.
WARNING: icmp6 normalizations disabled because not inline.
Frag3 global config:
    Max frags: 65536
    Fragment memory cap: 4194304 bytes
Frag3 engine config:
    Bound Address: default
    Target-based policy: WINDOWS
    Fragment timeout: 180 seconds
    Fragment min_ttl:   1
    Fragment Anomalies: Alert
    Overlap Limit:     10
    Min fragment Length:     100
      Max Expected Streams: 768
Stream global config:
    Track TCP sessions: ACTIVE
    Max TCP sessions: 262144
    TCP cache pruning timeout: 30 seconds
    TCP cache nominal timeout: 3600 seconds
    Memcap (for reassembly packet storage): 8388608
    Track UDP sessions: ACTIVE
    Max UDP sessions: 131072
    UDP cache pruning timeout: 30 seconds
    UDP cache nominal timeout: 180 seconds
    Track ICMP sessions: INACTIVE
    Track IP sessions: INACTIVE
    Log info if session memory consumption exceeds 1048576
    Send up to 2 active responses
    Wait at least 5 seconds between responses
    Protocol Aware Flushing: ACTIVE
        Maximum Flush Point: 16000
Stream TCP Policy config:
    Bound Address: default
    Reassembly Policy: WINDOWS
    Timeout: 180 seconds
    Limit on TCP Overlaps: 10
    Maximum number of bytes to queue per session: 1048576
    Maximum number of segs to queue per session: 2621
    Options:
        Require 3-Way Handshake: YES
        3-Way Handshake Timeout: 180
        Detect Anomalies: YES
    Reassembly Ports:
      21 client (Footprint) 
      22 client (Footprint) 
      23 client (Footprint) 
      25 client (Footprint) 
      42 client (Footprint) 
      53 client (Footprint) 
      79 client (Footprint) 
      80 client (Footprint) server (Footprint)
      81 client (Footprint) server (Footprint)
      109 client (Footprint) 
      110 client (Footprint) 
      111 client (Footprint) 
      113 client (Footprint) 
      119 client (Footprint) 
      135 client (Footprint) 
      136 client (Footprint) 
      137 client (Footprint) 
      139 client (Footprint) 
      143 client (Footprint) 
      161 client (Footprint) 
      additional ports configured but not printed.
Stream UDP Policy config:
    Timeout: 180 seconds
HttpInspect Config:
    GLOBAL CONFIG
      Detect Proxy Usage:       NO
      IIS Unicode Map Filename: /etc/snort/unicode.map
      IIS Unicode Map Codepage: 1252
      Memcap used for logging URI and Hostname: 150994944
      Max Gzip Memory: 838860
      Max Gzip Sessions: 2723
      Gzip Compress Depth: 65535
      Gzip Decompress Depth: 65535
    DEFAULT SERVER CONFIG:
      Server profile: All
      Ports (PAF): 80 81 311 383 591 593 901 1220 1414 1741 1830 2301 2381 2809 3037 3128 3702 4343 4848 5250 6988 7000 7001 7144 7145 7510 7777 7779 8000 8008 8014 8028 8080 8085 8088 8090 8118 8123 8180 8181 8243 8280 8300 8800 8888 8899 9000 9060 9080 9090 9091 9443 9999 11371 34443 34444 41080 50002 55555 
      Server Flow Depth: 0
      Client Flow Depth: 0
      Max Chunk Length: 500000
      Small Chunk Length Evasion: chunk size <= 10, threshold >= 5 times
      Max Header Field Length: 750
      Max Number Header Fields: 100
      Max Number of WhiteSpaces allowed with header folding: 200
      Inspect Pipeline Requests: YES
      URI Discovery Strict Mode: NO
      Allow Proxy Usage: NO
      Disable Alerting: NO
      Oversize Dir Length: 500
      Only inspect URI: NO
      Normalize HTTP Headers: NO
      Inspect HTTP Cookies: YES
      Inspect HTTP Responses: YES
      Extract Gzip from responses: YES
      Decompress response files:   
      Unlimited decompression of gzip data from responses: YES
      Normalize Javascripts in HTTP Responses: YES
      Max Number of WhiteSpaces allowed with Javascript Obfuscation in HTTP responses: 200
      Normalize HTTP Cookies: NO
      Enable XFF and True Client IP: NO
      Log HTTP URI data: NO
      Log HTTP Hostname data: NO
      Extended ASCII code support in URI: NO
      Ascii: YES alert: NO
      Double Decoding: YES alert: NO
      %U Encoding: YES alert: YES
      Bare Byte: YES alert: NO
      UTF 8: YES alert: NO
      IIS Unicode: YES alert: NO
      Multiple Slash: YES alert: NO
      IIS Backslash: YES alert: NO
      Directory Traversal: YES alert: NO
      Web Root Traversal: YES alert: NO
      Apache WhiteSpace: YES alert: NO
      IIS Delimiter: YES alert: NO
      IIS Unicode Map: GLOBAL IIS UNICODE MAP CONFIG
      Non-RFC Compliant Characters: 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 
      Whitespace Characters: 0x09 0x0b 0x0c 0x0d 
rpc_decode arguments:
    Ports to decode RPC on: 111 32770 32771 32772 32773 32774 32775 32776 32777 32778 32779 
    alert_fragments: INACTIVE
    alert_large_fragments: INACTIVE
    alert_incomplete: INACTIVE
    alert_multiple_requests: INACTIVE
FTPTelnet Config:
    GLOBAL CONFIG
      Inspection Type: stateful
      Check for Encrypted Traffic: YES alert: NO
      Continue to check encrypted data: YES
    TELNET CONFIG:
      Ports: 23 
      Are You There Threshold: 20
      Normalize: YES
      Detect Anomalies: YES
    FTP CONFIG:
      FTP Server: default
        Ports (PAF): 21 2100 3535 
        Check for Telnet Cmds: YES alert: YES
        Ignore Telnet Cmd Operations: YES alert: YES
        Ignore open data channels: NO
      FTP Client: default
        Check for Bounce Attacks: YES alert: YES
        Check for Telnet Cmds: YES alert: YES
        Ignore Telnet Cmd Operations: YES alert: YES
        Max Response Length: 256
SMTP Config:
    Ports: 25 465 587 691 
    Inspection Type: Stateful
    Normalize: ATRN AUTH BDAT DATA DEBUG EHLO EMAL ESAM ESND ESOM ETRN EVFY EXPN HELO HELP IDENT MAIL NOOP ONEX QUEU QUIT RCPT RSET SAML SEND STARTTLS SOML TICK TIME TURN TURNME VERB VRFY X-EXPS XADR XAUTH XCIR XEXCH50 XGEN XLICENSE X-LINK2STATE XQUE XSTA XTRN XUSR CHUNKING X-ADAT X-DRCP X-ERCP X-EXCH50 
    Ignore Data: No
    Ignore TLS Data: No
    Ignore SMTP Alerts: No
    Max Command Line Length: 512
    Max Specific Command Line Length: 
       ATRN:255 AUTH:246 BDAT:255 DATA:246 DEBUG:255 
       EHLO:500 EMAL:255 ESAM:255 ESND:255 ESOM:255 
       ETRN:246 EVFY:255 EXPN:255 HELO:500 HELP:500 
       IDENT:255 MAIL:260 NOOP:255 ONEX:246 QUEU:246 
       QUIT:246 RCPT:300 RSET:246 SAML:246 SEND:246 
       SIZE:255 STARTTLS:246 SOML:246 TICK:246 TIME:246 
       TURN:246 TURNME:246 VERB:246 VRFY:255 X-EXPS:246 
       XADR:246 XAUTH:246 XCIR:246 XEXCH50:246 XGEN:246 
       XLICENSE:246 X-LINK2STATE:246 XQUE:246 XSTA:246 XTRN:246 
       XUSR:246 
    Max Header Line Length: 1000
    Max Response Line Length: 512
    X-Link2State Alert: Yes
    Drop on X-Link2State Alert: No
    Alert on commands: None
    Alert on unknown commands: No
    SMTP Memcap: 838860
    MIME Max Mem: 838860
    Base64 Decoding: Enabled
    Base64 Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Quoted-Printable Decoding: Enabled
    Quoted-Printable Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding: Enabled
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction: Enabled
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction Depth: Unlimited
    Log Attachment filename: Enabled
    Log MAIL FROM Address: Enabled
    Log RCPT TO Addresses: Enabled
    Log Email Headers: Enabled
    Email Hdrs Log Depth: 1464
SSH config: 
    Autodetection: ENABLED
    Challenge-Response Overflow Alert: ENABLED
    SSH1 CRC32 Alert: ENABLED
    Server Version String Overflow Alert: ENABLED
    Protocol Mismatch Alert: ENABLED
    Bad Message Direction Alert: DISABLED
    Bad Payload Size Alert: DISABLED
    Unrecognized Version Alert: DISABLED
    Max Encrypted Packets: 20  
    Max Server Version String Length: 100  
    MaxClientBytes: 19600 (Default) 
    Ports:
    22
DCE/RPC 2 Preprocessor Configuration
  Global Configuration
    DCE/RPC Defragmentation: Enabled
    Memcap: 102400 KB
    Events: co 
    SMB Fingerprint policy: Disabled
  Server Default Configuration
    Policy: WinXP
    Detect ports (PAF)
      SMB: 139 445 
      TCP: 135 
      UDP: 135 
      RPC over HTTP server: 593 
      RPC over HTTP proxy: None
    Autodetect ports (PAF)
      SMB: None
      TCP: 1025-65535 
      UDP: 1025-65535 
      RPC over HTTP server: 1025-65535 
      RPC over HTTP proxy: None
    Invalid SMB shares: C$ D$ ADMIN$ 
    Maximum SMB command chaining: 3 commands
    SMB file inspection: Disabled
DNS config: 
    DNS Client rdata txt Overflow Alert: ACTIVE
    Obsolete DNS RR Types Alert: INACTIVE
    Experimental DNS RR Types Alert: INACTIVE
    Ports: 53
SSLPP config:
    Encrypted packets: not inspected
    Ports:
      443      465      563      636      989
      992      993      994      995     7801
     7802     7900     7901     7902     7903
     7904     7905     7906     7907     7908
     7909     7910     7911     7912     7913
     7914     7915     7916     7917     7918
     7919     7920
    Server side data is trusted
    Maximum SSL Heartbeat length: 0
Sensitive Data preprocessor config: 
    Global Alert Threshold: 25
    Masked Output: DISABLED
SIP config: 
    Max number of sessions: 40000  
    Max number of dialogs in a session: 4 (Default) 
    Status: ENABLED
    Ignore media channel: DISABLED
    Max URI length: 512  
    Max Call ID length: 80  
    Max Request name length: 20 (Default) 
    Max From length: 256 (Default) 
    Max To length: 256 (Default) 
    Max Via length: 1024 (Default) 
    Max Contact length: 512  
    Max Content length: 2048  
    Ports:
    5060    5061    5600
    Methods:
      invite cancel ack bye register options refer subscribe update join info message notify benotify do qauth sprack publish service unsubscribe prack
IMAP Config:
    Ports: 143 
    IMAP Memcap: 838860
    MIME Max Mem: 838860
    Base64 Decoding: Enabled
    Base64 Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Quoted-Printable Decoding: Enabled
    Quoted-Printable Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding: Enabled
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction: Enabled
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction Depth: Unlimited
POP Config:
    Ports: 110 
    POP Memcap: 838860
    MIME Max Mem: 838860
    Base64 Decoding: Enabled
    Base64 Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Quoted-Printable Decoding: Enabled
    Quoted-Printable Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding: Enabled
    Unix-to-Unix Decoding Depth: Unlimited
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction: Enabled
    Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction Depth: Unlimited
Modbus config: 
    Ports:
    502
DNP3 config: 
    Memcap: 262144
    Check Link-Layer CRCs: ENABLED
    Ports:
    20000
Reputation config: 
WARNING: Can't find any whitelist/blacklist entries. Reputation Preprocessor disabled.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Initializing rule chains...
0 Snort rules read
    0 detection rules
    0 decoder rules
    0 preprocessor rules
0 Option Chains linked into 0 Chain Headers
0 Dynamic rules
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

+-------------------[Rule Port Counts]---------------------------------------
|             tcp     udp    icmp      ip
|     src       0       0       0       0
|     dst       0       0       0       0
|     any       0       0       0       0
|      nc       0       0       0       0
|     s+d       0       0       0       0
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------

+-----------------------[detection-filter-config]------------------------------
| memory-cap : 1048576 bytes
+-----------------------[detection-filter-rules]-------------------------------
| none
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

+-----------------------[rate-filter-config]-----------------------------------
| memory-cap : 1048576 bytes
+-----------------------[rate-filter-rules]------------------------------------
| none
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

+-----------------------[event-filter-config]----------------------------------
| memory-cap : 1048576 bytes
+-----------------------[event-filter-global]----------------------------------
+-----------------------[event-filter-local]-----------------------------------
| none
+-----------------------[suppression]------------------------------------------
| none
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rule application order: activation->dynamic->pass->drop->sdrop->reject->alert->log
Verifying Preprocessor Configurations!

        --== Initialization Complete ==--

   ,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
  o"  )~   Version 2.9.7.0 GRE (Build 149) 
   ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/contact#team
           Copyright (C) 2014 Cisco and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
           Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
           Using libpcap version 1.1.1
           Using PCRE version: 8.12 2011-01-15
           Using ZLIB version: 1.2.3.4

           Rules Engine: SF_SNORT_DETECTION_ENGINE  Version 2.4  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_FTPTELNET  Version 1.2  <Build 13>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SIP  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_IMAP  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_POP  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_REPUTATION  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SDF  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNP3  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SMTP  Version 1.1  <Build 9>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSLPP  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_GTP  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNS  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSH  Version 1.1  <Build 3>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DCERPC2  Version 1.0  <Build 3>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_MODBUS  Version 1.1  <Build 1>

Snort successfully validated the configuration!
Snort exiting
```

Comment: Did you include the local.conf file in snort.conf and is it pointing to the correct file and are the permissions set correctly on that file? i.e. in your snort.conf file you should have the following line:  

include $RULE_PATH/local.conf

Comment: Yeah. I had done that. I still haven't figured out why it is not working.

Comment: I had set the permissions using this command. 'sudo chmod -R 5775 /etc/snort'. I did the whole installation again it is still not able to load the rules.

Comment: Is it necessary to have two network interfaces (eth0 and eth1). one network interface dedicated to managing the machine and connected to the actual LAN and the other network interface dedicated for sniffing network traffic. I have just used eth0.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put this rule in local.rules

**alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any ( msg :" ICMP test "; sid :10000001; rev :001;)** . It did not work for me. Put this rule set in your local.rules instead

**alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"ICMP Packet"; sid:477; rev:3;)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your rule to /etc/snort/rules/local.rules. The guide has that mistake so instead of local.conf, you have to use the local.rules. 
Before that step the guide says that uncomment the line(545 if im right) what containes include $RULE_PATH/local.rules. Thats why u have to use local.rules because snort ll use that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned solution:

```
alert icmp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP test"; icode:0; itype:8; sid:100000001;)
```

Make sure your $HOME_NET is configured in snort.conf to use your IP-address (or use any any)

itype 8 is ICMP Echo Request with icode 0, which in this case triggers the alarm.
Just like if you use SYN flag (flag:S;) for example in incoming FTP connection to trigger the alarm.

You can write it inside local.rules or create your own, as long as .rules file is inside `/etc/snort/rules` with every other .rules file and it's correct in `snort.conf = var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules`

restart snort after snort.conf file editing with systemctl restart snort and if needed, check it's status with systemctl status snort (last command in systemctl is snort or snortd)

try starting snort with:

```
snort -A console -q -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i <your listening NIC>
```

and ping it.

Hope this helps.